# Scons missing builtin Builder for "Jar"

Tags: scons

I'm using an (admittedly aged) version of Scons (2.0.1; upgrading possible but might be difficult), and I'm having trouble with the "Jar" builder. Specifically, it isn't available, and I don't know why. The "JavaClassFile" builder is available and works correctly, but it can't build my jar, failing with this error:

scons: Reading SConscript files ...
AttributeError: 'SConsEnvironment' object has no attribute 'Jar':
  File "/home/fred/comms/SConstruct", line 183:
    envWithJava.Jar(target='util/myproject.jar', source=['util/myproject.class', 'util/jasypt.jar', 'util/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar', 'util/Manifest.txt'])

The relevant SConstruct excerpt:

env.Jar(target='util/myproject.jar', source=['util/myproject.class', 'util/jasypt.jar', 'util/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-152.jar', 'util/Manifest.txt'])

"BUILDERS:" from env.Dump() does not list "Jar", but has numerous others, and builds C, C++, Flex and other sources fine.

I'm mainly looking for a way to debug what's happening inside of Scons to make it skip the builder. The jar command is in the same dir as javac, and that builder works, so it doesn't seem path related. The Python files that have the Jar references are present in the lib used by Scons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you either have no "jar" executable installed (can you call it on the command line?), or it's located in a path that hasn't been properly propagated to your Environment. See also #1 of the "most asked FAQs" at http://scons.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions and the very java-specific bug report at http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2730 .

Comment: The Tigris bug report was exactly the problem. How the heck did you find that? My Google-fu failed me, and I'm usually pretty good at it.

Comment: I bet it is...back when I fixed the mentioned bug, I added a comment in the source for the Jar builder, referencing the issue ticket. Looks like the extra work paid off... ;)